# Is there an equivalent of 'REGEXP_SUBSTR' of SnowFlake in PySpark?

Tags: sql, regex, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there an equivalent of Snowflake's `REGEXP_SUBSTR` in `PySpark`/`spark-sql`?

`REGEXP_EXTRACT` exists, but that doesn't support as many parameters as are supported by `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.

Here is a link to [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html).

Here is a link to [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://docs.data.world/documentation/sql/reference/functions/regexp_extract.html).

More specifically, I'm looking for alternatives for `position`, `occurrence` and `regex parameters` which are supported by Snowflake's `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.

**position**: Number of characters from the beginning of the string where the function starts searching for matches.

**occurrence**:  Specifies which occurrence of the pattern to match. The function skips the first occurrence - 1 matches.

**regex_parameters**: I'm looking specifically for the parameter 'e', which does the following:
*extract sub-matches*.

So the query is something like:

`REGEXP_SUBSTR(string, pattern, 1, 2, 'e', 2)`.

**Sample Input**: `It was the best of times, it was the worst in times.`

**Expected output**: `worst`

Assuming **string1** = `It was the best of times, it was the worst in times.`

Equivalent SF query:

`SELECT regexp_substr(string1, 'the(\\W+)(\\w+)', 1, 2, 'e', 2)`

Comment: What functionality are you looking for?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff please have a look at the updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best things about Spark is that you don't have to rely on a vendor to create a library of functions for you.  You can create a User Defined Function in python and use it in a Spark SQL Statement.  EG staring with

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast,col, lit, concat, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, IntegerType, StringType

import re

def regexp_substr(subject:str, pattern:str, position:int,occurance:int) -> str:
    s = subject[position:]
    searchResult = re.search(pattern,s)
    if searchResult:
        return searchResult.group(occurance)
    return None

#bench testing the python function
string1 = 'It was the best of times, it was the worst in times.'
pattern = 'the(\W+)(\w+)'

# print(pattern)
rv = regexp_substr(string1, pattern, 1,2)
print(rv)

# register for use in python
regexp_substr_udf = udf(regexp_substr , StringType())

# register for use in Spark SQL
spark.udf.register("REGEXP_SUBSTR", regexp_substr, StringType())

#craeate a spark DataFrame
df = spark.range(100).withColumn("s",lit(string1))
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
```

then you can run Spark SQL queries like

```
%%sql

select *, REGEXP_SUBSTR(s,'the(\\W+)(\\w+)',1,2) ex from df
```

Comment: For the OP, I had to replace `re.search` with `re.findall`. However, the idea was to the point.